# C# Array is empty after using Array.Sort()

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm generating six numbers, adding them to an array and displaying them in labels, after I attempt to sort the integers and then display them again, all of them return the value "0"

```
int[] generatedNums = new int[6]; //Array containing generated integers

 protected void BtnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Random newRandom = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {  
        generatedNums[i] = newRandom.Next(1, 50);
    }

    lblNum1.Text = generatedNums[0].ToString();
    lblNum2.Text = generatedNums[1].ToString();
    lblNum3.Text = generatedNums[2].ToString();
    lblNum4.Text = generatedNums[3].ToString();
    lblNum5.Text = generatedNums[4].ToString();
    lblNum6.Text = generatedNums[5].ToString();

}

protected void BtnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Array.Sort(generatedNums);

    lblNum1.Text = generatedNums[0].ToString();
    lblNum2.Text = generatedNums[1].ToString();
    lblNum3.Text = generatedNums[2].ToString();
    lblNum4.Text = generatedNums[3].ToString();
    lblNum5.Text = generatedNums[4].ToString();
    lblNum6.Text = generatedNums[5].ToString();
}
```

I combined both methods into one and it works fine, any help?

Comment: Can you show the additional code where `generatedNums` is declared?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you only run the second method, then your array won't have been filled with numbers, hence they are all zero...

Comment: In what context is this code run?  Is this on a desktop application or on the web?

Comment: If it was me, I would simply put a breakpoint on the line of code that calls Sort, and inspect what's in the array before the Sort, and then after. Almost zero chance that Sort is actually changing the elements all to zero. I think you'll find the problem lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I'm guessing this is in an old-school asp.net webpage.  This is why you don't make a stateless programming environment look like it is stateful.

Comment: On a web form, I believe that the sort is the problem. But I have to use the sort, for my class.

Comment: Sort is not the problem. Thinking that your class instance (and thus the contents of generatedNums) survives from one post to another is the problem. Comment out the Sort, and you will see the values still all go to zero.

Comment: Okay, and how do I stop the array from becoming empty again?

Comment: Don't think of it as "becoming" empty. Think of it as the server throwing everything away as soon as it's done processing a request. When the next request comes in, everything is created anew, from scratch.

Comment: Okay, well how can I get the array to carry its contents over?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're forgetting that the web server doesn't preserve the state of the `generatedNums` array between requests.  Web Forms, like most web frameworks, is stateless.  When you attempt to sort the array, you will need to regenerate the list or read it out of the labels.  Your class members are not persisted between requests.

Comment: So how can I keep the array's value between requests?

Answer (score 0):

you only initialize values 0 - 4

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

but you display 0 - 5

```
lblNum1.Text = generatedNums[0].ToString();
lblNum2.Text = generatedNums[1].ToString();
lblNum3.Text = generatedNums[2].ToString();
lblNum4.Text = generatedNums[3].ToString();
lblNum5.Text = generatedNums[4].ToString();
lblNum6.Text = generatedNums[5].ToString();
```

It would also help if you showed the declaration generatedNums

Answer (score 0):

Ahh this being a web server is an extremely important detail
and you can keep the variable from clearing like this

```
private int[] generatedNums
{
    get { return (int[])HttpContext.Current.Session["generatedNums"]; }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["generatedNums"] = value; }
}
```

in your constructor or initializer you can add this

```
if (generatedNums == null)
    generatedNums = new int[6];
```

or better you can set it upon starting up the server

Comment: But read this first http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160947/should-session-variables-be-avoided .

Comment: I agree completely with hatchet use responsibly

Comment: Okay, I'm now getting an "System.NullReferenceException", when assigning the random numbers to the array. I have read the forum before

Comment: ahh thats because you have not set the generatedNums the first times I will edit my answer for you